# Select range between a word and blank row and move to a new sheet

Tags: excel, import, move, vba

I have imported tables from a URL into sheet 1. There are 2 types of tables and the number of tables can vary on each import. Table 1 starts with the word RANK in Column A and ends with 2 blank rows. Table 2 starts with the word PLACE in column A and ends with 2 blank rows. The number of rows will also vary every time but the number of columns is always constant.

I need to select each table/section and put all of the Table 1's on a sheet and all of the Table 2's on a separate sheet with 2 empty rows between them.

It seems the only information I can find is people looking to delete empty rows or paste something in the first empty row. I'm hopeful that someone on here can help me.

Edit: I'm using Excel 2013. 
Not sure if it matters but after deleting the blank columns, the number of columns in the RANK sections is 12, and the number of columns in the PLACE sections is 7.

Here is the code I am using.

```
Sub Test_1()
'
' Test_1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.RandomSite/id_6264", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "6264"
        .Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
   ' Dimension variables.
   Y = False              ' Change this to True if you want to
                          ' delete rows 1, 3, 5, and so on.
   I = 1
   Set xRng = Selection

   ' Loop once for every row in the selection.
   For xCounter = 1 To xRng.Rows.Count

       ' If Y is True, then...
       If Y = True Then

           ' ...delete an entire row of cells.
           xRng.Cells(I).EntireRow.Delete

       ' Otherwise...
       Else

           ' ...increment I by one so we can cycle through range.
           I = I + 1

       End If

       ' If Y is True, make it False; if Y is False, make it True.
       Y = Not Y

   Next xCounter
      ' Dimension variables.
   Y = True              ' Change this to True if you want to
                          ' delete columns 1, 3, 5, and so on.
   I = 1
   Set xRng = Selection

   ' Loop once for every column in the selection.
   For xCounter = 1 To xRng.Columns.Count

       ' If Y is True, then...
       If Y = True Then

           ' ...delete an entire column of cells.
           xRng.Cells(I).EntireColumn.Delete

       ' Otherwise...
       Else

           ' ...increment I by one so we can cycle through range.
           I = I + 1

       End If

       ' If Y is True, make it False; if Y is False, make it True.
       Y = Not Y

   Next xCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you importing the tables from 'a URL' directly to 'a sheet' and 'a separate sheet'?

Comment: I tried but was never able to succeed. It was easier for me to use xlAllTables.  Since the number of tables varies I thought my options were to import All tables or specify which ones (1,2,4, etc.) which requires manual entry each time.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Tables imported from 'a URL' typically have a header row and while they may have individual blank cells, there are usually not complete blank rows or columns in the data matrix. This makes them ideal to be referenced with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx). The `split_Rank_Places` should work well for those.

If you have blank rows in your tables then a different method of determining the size of the table is necessary. In these cases, `split_Rank_Places2` would be appropriate.

```
Sub split_Rank_Places()
    Dim v As Long, vTBLs As Variant
    Dim fnd As Range

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False
    vTBLs = Array("PLACE", "a sheet", _
                  "RANK", "a separate sheet")

    With Worksheets("sheet 1")
        For v = LBound(vTBLs) To UBound(vTBLs) Step 2
            On Error Resume Next
            Worksheets(vTBLs(v + 1)).Delete
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            .Copy After:=Worksheets(.Index)
            With Worksheets(.Index + 1)
                .Name = vTBLs(v + 1)
                With .Columns(1)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set fnd = .Find(What:=vTBLs(v), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
                    Do While Not fnd Is Nothing
                        With fnd.CurrentRegion
                            With .Resize(.Rows.Count + 2, 1)
                                .EntireRow.Delete
                            End With
                        End With
                        Set fnd = .FindNext(After:=.Cells(1))
                    Loop
                    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
                End With
            End With
        Next v
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL

End Sub

Sub split_Rank_Places2()
    Dim v As Long, vTBLs As Variant
    Dim fnd As Range, stp As Long

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False
    vTBLs = Array("RANK", "PLACE", "a sheet", _
                  "PLACE", "RANK", "a separate sheet")

    With Worksheets("sheet 1")
        For v = LBound(vTBLs) To UBound(vTBLs) Step 3
            On Error Resume Next
            Worksheets(vTBLs(v + 2)).Delete
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            .Copy After:=Worksheets(.Index)
            With Worksheets(.Index + 1)
                .Name = vTBLs(v + 2)
                With .Columns(1)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set fnd = .Find(What:=vTBLs(v + 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
                    Do While Not fnd Is Nothing
                        If CBool(Application.CountIf(fnd.Resize(Rows.Count - fnd.Row, 1), vTBLs(v))) Then
                            stp = Application.Match(vTBLs(v), fnd.Resize(Rows.Count - fnd.Row, 1), 0)
                            fnd.Resize(stp - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                        Else
                            fnd.Resize(Rows.Count - fnd.Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                        End If
                        Set fnd = .FindNext(After:=.Cells(1))
                    Loop
                End With
            End With
        Next v
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL

End Sub


Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

Sometimes it's easier to get rid of what you don't want rather than try and duplicate what you want.

Comment: I must have one of the untypical situations because when I imported every other row and column was blank.  I ran a macro to remove all of blanks but that is all I could find out so far.  Also, thank you for your help.  I just ran your code and I got a "Compile Error". Sub or Function not defined.  This was selected: appTGGL

Comment: It would seem that you didn't copy the companion `Sub appTGGL` procedure I include at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Oops. I have added that procedure to the bottom and ran the macro again. The first time I ran it, "a sheet" and "a separate sheet" were created but nothing was moved from sheet 1.  I thought it had to do with me adding the new procedure, so I quit Excel, reopened the project and ran your macro again.  This time I am not getting anything to work. I'm not getting any errors but I am also not getting any sheets created.